# PLS-00103: Create trigger for sequence number oracle

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

I have this script. Basically increase one of the primary key in a table.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FORCE TRIGGER SISD_OWNER.TRG_SN_MAP_UNIT_RELA_SEQ
BEFORE INSERT ON SISD_OWNER.ADV_SN_MAP_UNIT_RELA
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
  m_next_seq_num NUMBER := 0;
BEGIN
  IF :new.SEQUENCE_NUMBER is null THEN
    select
        ADV_SN_MAP_UNIT_RELA_SEQ.NextVal
    into m_next_seq_num
    from dual;
    :new.SEQUENCE_NUMBER := m_next_seq_num;
  END IF;
END;
```

When run on sqlplus (cmd), I got:

```
LINE/COL ERROR
-------- -----------------------------------------------------------------
2/28     PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting
     one of the following:
     * & = - + ; < / > at in is mod remainder not rem
     <an exponent (**)> <> or != or ~= >= <= <> and or like like2
     like4 likec between || multiset member submultiset
```

Not sure what exactly is the error?

Comment: keep one of the delimiter like `/` at the end of the trigger

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the keyword `FORCE`.  That option does not exist for triggers.  (Although I wish it did - it would be nice sometimes to create a trigger before the table or sequence existed.)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you have a database version 11g or higher.
Then use new features that simplify the code and increase productivity.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER SISD_OWNER.TRG_SN_MAP_UNIT_RELA_SEQ
BEFORE INSERT ON SISD_OWNER.ADV_SN_MAP_UNIT_RELA
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE

BEGIN
  IF :new.SEQUENCE_NUMBER is null THEN
    :new.SEQUENCE_NUMBER := ADV_SN_MAP_UNIT_RELA_SEQ.NextVal;
  END IF;
END;
```